# 301 Redirect including Subdomain and Folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains:

subdomain.domain.tld
subdomain.domain.tld2

They both are linking to the same ROOT Folder, lets call it "start".
So if I enter one of the both urls, It will open the index file in "start".

Now I have a subfolder in this "start" folder, lets call it "subfolder".
I can open this subfolder by entering 
subdomain.domain.tld/subfolder/ OR
subdomain.domain.tld2/subfolder/

I wish that if someone calls
subdomain.domain.tld/subfolder/
it will 301 to
subdomain.domain.tld2/subfolder/

Also, if someone would call
subdomain.domain.tld/subfolder/subxyz/page=123
it will 301 to
subdomain.domain.tld2/subfolder/subxyz/page=123

I created a .htaccess in the "subfolder" with the following code, but its not working. I tried also a bunch of other Redirect Codes that I found here on Stackoverflow, but none is working for me so far. Any hel is welcome!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://subdomain.domain.tld/subfolder/[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.tld2/subfolder/[L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--If http_host is "subdomain.domain.tld"--#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.tld$
#-- And the uri is /subfolder/--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subfolder
#--Then, redirect the uri to another host --#
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://subdomain.domain.tld2/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```